# Hey, i need help in batch to make it copy everything in 1 folder to another folder

Tags: batch-file, copy, directory

im working on a script that have few folders and i don't really understand how to make an config for this but i don't need it.
i have setup a script config inside

```
Set cfg=cfg2
Set txt=txt2
Set rar=rar2
```

cfg2, txt2, rar2 are in a diffrent directory

the files in cfg are cfg files but theres alot of them.
this also goes for txt & rar too.

i want a copy script that copies all cfg files (and only cfg files) into the cfg2 file that are in another directory.
and then this goes again for the txt & rar files.

I also know the code for move but i really want to copy it
cause on move you just do
move "txt/*.txt" %txt% and thats kinda what i want to do but that aint working

Comment: I suggest looking at this reliable source on the COPY command. http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at robocopy from microsoft. 
Something like the below should work;

```
robocopy /s \path\cfg \path\cfg2 *.cfg
```

Comment: I found out that XCOPY Was actualy easier to use
The code: `XCOPY "%XPath%\*.%Xformat%" "%Xsortedfolder%"`
Also thanks for the idea of using other copy commands, didn't know they existed

Comment: I tend to prefer robocopy as you can add the /LOG: switch and log to a file for regular tasks, but xcopy is just as good. Robocopy is built into windows after windows vista iirc.